# In PHP, I encoded a JSON array from mySQL . i want to decode it in different php file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

In Php, I encoded a JSON array from MySQL table . i want to decode it in different Php file . and i want to access the data through JavaScript from different file. anyone please help me.

MY code is:

```
$serverName = "(local)";

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"sample");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) 
{
     echo "Connection established.<br/>";
}

else

{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br/>";

     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
    $str="Select * from sam1";

    $res=sqlsrv_query($conn,$str) or die("Error !");

    $response=array();

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{

$response['tdata'][]=$row;

}
print(json_encode($response));
```

Output is :

```
 {"tdata":[{"id":"1","name":"aaa"},{"id":"2","name":"bbb"},{"id":"3","name":"ccc"}]}
```

My decode Function is:

```
$data = file_get_contents('db2.php');

$data1 = json_decode($data, true);

print($data1);
```

but its not working..

Comment: What's the problem? Your description makes it difficult to identify, please clarify.

Comment: Please format code with the `{}` button.

Comment: Can you use `sqlsrv` for mysql now? I thought it was just for SQL Server.

Comment: What does the `db2.php` file do? What does it output? If you run `var_dump($data)` in your decode file you may find it outputs the raw PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return `JSON` encoded string it is best if you send a proper headers. You should return `JSON` like that (you can still use `print` function):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now, when you retrieve this output, send it to `json_decode` function that will return an object.

[json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

`file_get_contents` function retrieves content of the file, it does not parse it. To retrieve the content of the file:

- by calling it with an URL (**DO NOT USE THIS ONE** I am showing this method for the purpose of learning only, this function wont load URL if `allow_url_fopen` directive is `off`, instead you can use `curl` library ([here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)))

  ```
  $json = file_get_contents('www.example.com/db2.php');
  echo json_decode($json, true);
  ```
- by including it with a relative path

  ```
  $json = (include "db2.php");
  echo json_decode($json, true);
  ```

  in this particular scenario, `db2.php` has to use `return` statement like so

  ```
  return json_encode($response);
  ```
- by using `ob_*` with `include`, this time you do not need to `return` in `db2.php` file

  ```
  ob_start();
  include "db2.php";
  $json = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  echo json_decode($json, true);
  ```

Comment: Thank you friend.. but i din't get the answer.. :(

Comment: Thank you so much ya ... I got answer :) :) and thank you for explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're populating $data with the text of db2.php instead of the output from running the file in php. Try this:

```
$data = `php db2.php`
```

Comment: Thank you friend.. but i din't get the answer.. :(